# $f : V \to V$, $f (u) = u$, $f (v) = u+v$ then $\{u, v\}$ linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $V$ is a vector space, $f : V \to V$ is linear transformation $ u, v \in V \setminus \{0\}$ and $f ( u ) = u$, $f (v) = u + v$, show that set $\{u, v\}$ is linearly independent.

I am confused, is some information missing in the task?

Let $\alpha u + \beta v = 0$ for some scalar $ \alpha$, $\beta$.

Then $f(\alpha u + \beta v) = \alpha f(u) + \beta f(v) = 0$ because $f$ is linear transformation and must be $f (0) = 0$.

$$\alpha u + \beta ( u + v) = 0\\
(\alpha + \beta) u + \beta v = 0$$

I can't see that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must be zeroes to conclude that $\{u, v\}$ is independent.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Subtract $\alpha u+\beta v=0$ from your last equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I overlooked this

Answer (score 4):

The (original) statement is not true. In any vector space $V$ of nonzero dimension take $f:V\to V$ the identity, $u=\vec 0$ and $v$ any nonzero vector: then the equations hold, but $\{u,v\}=\{\vec0,v\}$ is a linearly dependent set due to the presence of the zero vector.

With the added condition that $u\neq\vec0$ the statement is true, as the only way for $u,v$ to be linearly dependent would now be for $v$ to be a scalar multiple of $u$, but the linear $f-I$ maps $u\mapsto\vec0$ while it maps $v\mapsto u$, which by hypothesis is not a scalar multiple of $\vec0$, contradicting linearity.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgorte to put $ u, v \in V \setminus \{0\}$. I will change now